# FourSquare API counts 5 lists, but only returns 3?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to get every ID from a list that a user created. This particular user has made 5 lists ( https://foursquare.com/griekenlandnet ), but the API returns on 3 of them. But the list count in the response does say 5? I tried to add `limit=100` to the API request, but it doesn't matter. I still only get 3 back.?

What is the trick to get all the list data back, and not only the first 3? I had the same problem with all the tips. Initially it only returned the first 30 responses, but that was fixed by adding the `limit=100` to the API request. Only this trick doesn't seem to work for the lists?

I'm aware that all the tips are part of the general list, but I would like to be able to only show tips from list A, or List b etc. But for that to work I would need to list ID, and not all of them show up.

Any idea's how to get all 5 lists back, instead of just the first 3? This is the response I get from the API http://tijmensmit.com/4sq-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the right endpoint? [users/self/lists?group=created](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/self/lists?group=created) should give you all lists created by a user.